# How to do HTTP Get/Post Request in Excel Office 365 for Mac?

Tags: vba, macos, excel-formula, office365, ms-office

I see Excel for Mac still has **no support for Power Query**, I need `powerquery` to import data from web (JSON) by issue an `HTTP` Get/Post with a query string to a web service.

I'm looking alternative using `Macro` or `VBA` but solutions here mostly outdated because it was for Office 2011/2016 or below **Office 365**.

Any Idea?

Comment: Sorry, but you're wrong. See: [Where is Get & Transform - Power Query](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/where-is-get-transform-power-query-e9332067-8e49-46fc-97ff-f2e1bfa0cb16). Go to bookmark: "Excel for Office 365 for Mac"
Quote: " The refresh functionality is live for all Office Insiders Fast customers in Excel for Mac, version 16.26 (19052200) and later. SQL Server connections are refreshable in version 16.35.218.0 and later."
See this too: [PQ for Mac](https://www.poweredsolutions.co/2019/07/15/power-query-in-excel-for-mac-first-impressions/)

Answer (score -3):

```
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
URL = "http://www.somedomain.com"
objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; 
Windows NT 5.0)"
objHTTP.send("")
```

Alternatively, for greater control over the HTTP request you can use WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1 in place of MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.

Comment: are you sure that works on a Mac?

Comment: Mac's cannot create ActiveX objects. The above "solution" is wrong.